# How to identify unique row value in SQL result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `Employee` and `EmployeeBenefit`.

`Employee` table has `Id` field

`EmployeeBenefit` table has `EmployeeId`, `CashValue` and `Percentage` fields.

---

The rules are:

`CashValue` and `Percentage` fields of `EmployeeBenefit` table are
    mutually exclusive; for any row in `EmployeeBenefit` table, once
    `CashValue` field has value, `Percentage` field should be null, vise versa.
  However, it is allowed that a row has `null` `CashValue` field and `null` `Percentage` field.

One employee can have multiple `EmployeeBenefit` rows(or have no row at
    all), and he/she can have no more than one `Percentage` field of
    `EmployeeBenefit` table with value.

The following is the example of `EmployeeBenefit` table:

```
+------------+-----------+------------+
| EmployeeId | CashValue | Percentage |
+------------+-----------+------------+
| A          | NULL      | 80         |
| A          | 20        | NULL       |
| A          | 15        | NULL       |
| A          | NULL      | NULL       |
| B          | NULL      | 60         |
| C          | 15        | NULL       |
| C          | 10        | NULL       |
+------------+-----------+------------+
```

I want to find out out whether the only benefit the employee has is `Percentage`.
What is the correct SQL Script?

I would like to make it look like:

```
 SELECT ......
 FROM Employee WITH(NOLOCK)
 OUTER APPLY
 (
   SELECT .......... AS HasOnlyPercentBenefit
   FROM EmployeeBenefit
   WHERE Employee.Id = EmployeeBenefit.EmployeeId
 )
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please tag with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` clause with `HAVING` to filter out the employee which has only  *Percentage*  benefit.

```
SELECT e.id  
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeBenefit b on b.EmployeeId = e.id
GROUP BY e.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1 AND
       MAX(b.Percentage) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

[[DEMO]](http://rextester.com/TMXX76705)

I would use conditional aggregation to get the EmployeeId which has only `null` for `CashValue` and only value for `Percentage`:

```
SELECT *, 'Yes' AS HasOnlyPercentBenefit
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN EmployeeBenefit eb ON e.Id = eb.EmployeeId
WHERE e.Id IN(
    SELECT e.Id 
    FROM Employee e
    INNER JOIN EmployeeBenefit eb ON e.Id = eb.EmployeeId
    GROUP BY e.Id
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN eb.CashValue IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1
        AND SUM(CASE WHEN eb.Percentage IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1)
```

[image]